# How to Normalize or standardize specific or selected features of a data set in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, standardized

I have data and the name of the data frame is Table, Table contains 15 features and I want to normalize only 3 features that are numeric data, the names of these features are 'rate', 'cost', and 'Total cost'.Please, how do I fix this?

I tried to extract the required features by filtering them using 
Table.loc[:,['rate',cost',total cost'] and passing to column_trans

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

from sklearn.preprocessing import  StandarScaler

column_trans = ColumnTransformer(

```
[('scaler', StandardScaler(),Table.loc[:,['rate','cost','Totalcost']]

remainder='passthrough')
```

column_trans.fit_transform(X)

I expected to get values between 0 and 1 for the normalized features.

But I got the following error message.

File "", line 5
    remainder='passthrough')
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Is there a missing `,` after `]] `?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

continuous_columns = ['rate','cost','Totalcost']
continuous_data= Table.loc[:, continuous_columns]
continuous_data['rate']= continuous_data['rate'].astype(float)
continuous_data['cost']= continuous_data['cost'].astype(float)
continuous_data['Totalcost']= continuous_data['Totalcost'].astype(float)
normalized_data = normalize(continuous_data)

normalized_data_df =pd.DataFrame(normalized_data , columns=continuous_columns) 
Table = Table.drop(continuous_columns, axis=1)
Final_data = pd.concat([Table, normalized_data_df ], axis=1)
```

Now `Final_data`  contains what you are looking for.

Comment: @ parthasarathy I got this error message:ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Looks like your columns are not float, so added a segment for type casting. Hope this helps

Comment: still same error message:ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: This error message was also given, value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  after removing the cwd from sys.path. Thanks

Comment: can you post a sample of your data and the entire trackback error?

Comment: I have finally fixed the problem, thanks to @ Parthasarathy for your immense assistance. But  I realized that the normalized_data is stored in the array without the column names 'rate', 'cost' and 'Total cost'.How do I use this normalized_data to build a model with the remaining features, do I add the normalized_data as a new feature to the original data frame and remove 'rate', 'cost' and 'Total cost'?

Comment: haha, thanks to @ Parthasarathy. This is awesome, Hope I can get to know you.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer can you please accept it and give an upvote to it :P?

Comment: Hi Subburaj, I just completed a classification project, before I started manipulating the features I first removed the "customerID" feature. Now after normalization and prediction, I want to present my output in just 2 columns,the first column will be the "CustomerID" and the second column will be the "the predictions in 0's and 1's". Please, do you have any ideas on how I can write a python code to display my output?

Answer (score 0):

smart contribution @ Parthasarathy, I noticed that one of the features was having NAN values 
and one other feature is an integer, so I converted the Nan values to 0  and also applied astype to the integer feature.  I applied the code below:

from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

continuous_columns = ['rate','cost','Totalcost']

continuous_data= Telco[continuous_columns]

continuous_data['rate']= continuous_data['rate'].astype(float)

normalized_data = normalize(continuous_data)